# Raster consists out of strips when using rasteriz

Tags: qgis, rasterization

When rasterizing X,Y,Z data from points in Qgis, I get a raster that consists out of a set of strips along the points. How do I generate a raster that fully covers the entire range of points (i.e. interpolating between them)?

[image]

Comment: There are different rasterization tools in  QGIS. What tool do you use? Can you add a screenshot showing the parameters of the tool, please?